# Obtener un backup full de una BD en un nodo standby || Cluster PostgreSQL

Tags: base-de-datos, linux, postgresql

Estoy tratando de obtener un backup full desde un nodo standby dentro de un cluster postgresql pero al ejecutar el comando obtengo el siguiente error:

```
pg_dump -U userbackup -W databasename > databasename.sql
```

> pg_dump: error: Dumping the contents of table "" failed: PQgetResult() failed.

> pg_dump: error: Error message from server: ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
> DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.

Con lo que investigué, modifiqué el parámetro `hot_standby_feedback` pero aún así no puedo generar el backup. ¿Me pueden asesorar si hay algún parámetro que deba modificar para poder ejecutarlo?

Comment: Hiciste el reload luego del cambio de configuración del parámetro?

Comment: @AnthonySotolongo Si, lo realice. Estuve revisando el mensaje obtenido en el server y  encontré con la sugerencia de modificar el parámetro max_standby_streaming_delay, el cual me ha ayudado a obtener el backup, sin embargo, he visto afectaciones en el tiempo de replicación.

Comment: Ese parámetro permite que puedas hacer las consultas en el standby, pero puede agregar un lag en la replicación